# How to create GEOGRAPHY type from coordinates other than WSG84 in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 2 coordinates (X and Y as floats), which represent the coordinates in LV95 coordinate system (EPSG:2056). How can I convert them to WSG84 and create a GEOGRAPHY type in Snowflake?

```
TO_GEOGRAPHY(ST_ASGEOJSON(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_MAKEGEOMPOINT("X","Y"), 2056, 4326)))
```

seems to work, but is it the way to do it?

Comment: If it works then it's the way to do it. I'm not sure what your question really is? Why don't you think this is the way to do it?

Comment: @NickW if it "works" it does not mean it's the best way to do it... i'm confused that the GEOGRAPHY type does not support oder coordinate Systems